# Simplecov with docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, simplecov

We recently migrated an app that we have to docker, and docker-compose.

While without docker, we used to run tests using `rspec spec` for example, while using docker we'd do the same thing using

```
docker-compose run app rspec spec
```

Now, in the old scenario, when I wanted a report for test coverage I'd use:

```
open coverage/index.html
```

Trying this with docker doesn't work though. Trying `docker-compose run app open coverage/index.html` doesnt work as well. In fact there is no folder called coverage under my project.

I tried looking online left and right for any examples of simple-cov with docker but can find none. Any hints to how to get this to work would be immensly appreciated.

open

Answer (score 0):

You should open the `coverage/index.html` from your local folder, not from the container folder.

When you say *"In fact there is no folder called coverage under my project."*, are you talking about the container project folder or the local project folder?

If you don't have the `/coverage` folder **on the container** after you ran the `rspec spec` command on it, make sure you have Simplecov started on your `spec/rails_helper` file at the very top of it:

```rb
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start
```

Once you have you run `rspec spec` on the container, the `/coverage` folder should be created and should automatically be synced to your local project folder, so you can open the `coverage/index.html` file on your browser.

In case it's not automatically synced, you can use the [`docker compose cp` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_cp/) to copy it into your local folder:

```bash
docker compose cp app:/app_root_folder/coverage/index.html ./coverage/index.html
```

Where:

- `app` is your container tag
- `app_root_folder` is your `WORKDIR` from your `Dockerfile`
- `./coverage/index.html` is the destination folder on your local machine.

Make sure you have the `/coverage` folder created on your local directory before trying to copy it from the container.

```
mkdir coverage
```